# Unable to update the same document inserted in same Mongodb transaction session

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have 2 collections of users and orders. I want to create a relation by inserting the documents for both collections and then updating the orders document with the _id of the user document. But when I do this in the same Mongodb transaction session, the order document is never updated! But if I disable the transaction, the code works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had to add the transaction session object in the options of the updateOne command of the MongoDB client.